# Перенос сайта на php-framework

Tags: php, framework

Добрый день.

Есть старый большой сайт.
Половина функционала сайта реализована  *по-старому* - файлы `.php` с лапшой из `html`,`php` и `sql`, лежат в корне сайта, путь `site.com/somefile.php`.

Другая половина функционала реализована  *по-новому* - в корне сайта подкаталог с mvc-фреймворком и там контроллеры, модели и отображения, путь `site.com/framework/somecontroller/somemethod`.

Главная страничка сайта работает *по-старому*.
Задача - перенести функционал главной странички *на фреймворк*, чтобы при этом не изменился путь.

Варианты решения задачи:

1. Развернуть вторую копию фреймворка в корне сайта, реализовать функционал главной странички как 
   `site.com/controller/method`, потихоньку перенести контроллеры модели и виды из
   `site.com/framework/` в `site.com/`. При этом надо будет как-то сохранить присутствие `/framework/` в ссылках.
2. Реализовать функционал главной странички сайта в `site.com/framework/`, а из `site.com/index.php`
   обращаться на  `site.com/framework/controller/method`, парсить и показывать контент.
3. Реализовать функционал главной странички сайта в `site.com/framework/`, затем содержимое каталога `/framework/` сделать корнем сайта. 
   При этом надо будет как-то сохранить присутствие `/framework/` в ссылках.

Какой вариант решения более адекватный? Как сохранить присутствие `/framework/` в ссылках в случае с вариантом 1 и 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@pavelchervov](/users/18707/pavelchervov), есть такой паттерн - фасад. Внешне не меняется вообще ничего, внутри активно переписывается. Просто первым делом реализуется do-nothing контроллер, который просто отдает запрос старому бэкенду, а потом постепенно вокруг наращивается приложение.

По поводу развернуть фреймворк прямо на сайте и переписывать код там же.

Не знаю, кто это вам посоветовал, но вы так никуда не уедете.